# How do I make my PHP API return JSON to a Javascript HTTP POST/GET request?

Tags: javascript, php, json, rest

I have been following the tutorial here http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-an-api-centric-web-application--net-23417 to create an "api eccentric web application" however the application only covers making requests from PHP.

Halfway through the tutorial you get to a point in which you can make requests by url in the browser e.g http://localhost/simpletodo_api/?controller=todo&action=create&title=test%20title&description=test%20description&due_date=12/08/2011&username=nikko&userpass=test1234

Here is the code of the front controller that receives the requests

```
<?php
// Define path to data folder
define('DATA_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/data'));

//include our models
include_once 'models/TodoItem.php';

//wrap the whole thing in a try-catch block to catch any wayward exceptions!
try {
    //get all of the parameters in the POST/GET request
    $params = $_REQUEST;

    //get the controller and format it correctly so the first
    //letter is always capitalized
    $controller = ucfirst(strtolower($params['controller']));

    //get the action and format it correctly so all the
    //letters are not capitalized, and append 'Action'
    $action = strtolower($params['action']).'Action';

    //check if the controller exists. if not, throw an exception
    if( file_exists("controllers/{$controller}.php") ) {
        include_once "controllers/{$controller}.php";
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Controller is invalid.');
    }

    //create a new instance of the controller, and pass
    //it the parameters from the request
    $controller = new $controller($params);

    //check if the action exists in the controller. if not, throw an exception.
    if( method_exists($controller, $action) === false ) {
        throw new Exception('Action is invalid.');
    }

    //execute the action
    $result['data'] = $controller->$action();
    $result['success'] = true;

} catch( Exception $e ) {
    //catch any exceptions and report the problem
    $result = array();
    $result['success'] = false;
    $result['errormsg'] = $e->getMessage();
}

//echo the result of the API call
echo json_encode($result);
exit();
```

So my question is, how would I make a request using Javascript in which it will return a JSON result?

EDIT: It appears I forgot to mention that this request will be made cross domain

Comment: have a look at json_encode in php . here is the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @georoot The code already uses json_encode. The question seems to be about how to make the appropriate request from JavaScript ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it to work, what I had attempted was a regular XMLHttpRequest in Javascript. The process was working as data was being saved but nothing was being returned. What I was missing was this line from the top of my index.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

I undertand that the * means all websites may access the API

Answer (score 1):

To call the API you need to make an AJAX request using JavaScript. Please read [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). This page have step by step guideline.

As you're sending JSON from your API so, after AJAX success you might need to [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the received content from API.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    echo -1;
    die;
}
$email=$_SESSION['user'];
$arr= array();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","usrname","password","databasename");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="select * from user where email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $arr[] = $row['u_id'];
        $arr[] = $row['f_name'];
        $arr[] = $row['l_name'];
        $arr[] = $row['email'];
        $arr[] = $row['telephone'];
        $arr[] = $row['address'];
}
echo json_encode($arr);
mysqli_close($con);?>
```

the above is a simple php script which get user's info from simple database.
You can call the above php script from javascript using ajax call as below:

```
function Get_User_Info(URL) {
    $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: URL,
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (response) {
                    var JSONArray = $.parseJSON(response);
                    connsole.log(JSONArray);
            });
        }
```

here the response contains the information from the database. and URL argument is the URL of you php page.
I hope that gonna help you.

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning this before but the request will be made cross domain, am I right thinking this way will not work?